# javascript to use value obtain using .html as a string in a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

let say i have this:

```
alert($('#child_check').html());
            if($('#child_check').html() != "Select..." || $('.funnel_items').val() == "5" || $('.funnel_items_sub').val() != "Select..."){
                return true;
            }else{
                alert("No Sub category selected!");
                return false;
            }
```

the .html return:

```
 &nbsp; No available selection for this action.
```

how will i be able to check if .html is equal to the string inputted since if i alert $('#test').html() it contains that string but the condition does not return true, so i was wondering what is wrong with this code?

also is it really not possible to use .html value as a string comparison for a codi

Thank you

Comment: Comparing the return value from `.html()` to another string should work fine. The problem is likely that your condition is wrong, or the return of `.html()` doesn't actually match. Without seeing the HTML it's pretty impossible to say.

Comment: added the value returned by .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to see if the result of .html() "contains" another string.

http://jsfiddle.net/XRWHF/

```
var haystack = $('#foo').html();
var needle = 'No available selection for this action.';
if (haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1) { // If needle is inside haystack
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes im trying to find if .html holds the string " No available selection for this action."